# notification Badge count not set using Apple Push notification - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to increment the badge number whenever a new notification is sent to a device using Apple Push Notification system.

I'm dispatching the notification using a Firebase Cloud Function and this is the code that does that:

```
exports.onEmotionCreated = functions.firestore
.document("Collection/{doc1}/Collection/{doc2}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const dict = snapshot.data();
  const toUid = dict.toUid;
  const fromUid = dict.fromUid;
  return db.collection("UserCollection").doc(fromUid).get().then((snap) => {
    const fromName = snap.data().name;
    return db.collection("UserCollection").doc(toUid).get().then((snapTo) => {
      const notificationToToken = snapTo.data().notificationToken;
      const notificationContent = {
        notification: {
          title: `${fromName} has sent you a message`,
          body: "Look what's up",
          icon: "default",
          sound: "customNotificationSound.wav",
        },
      };
      return admin.messaging()
          .sendToDevice(notificationToToken, notificationContent)
          .then((result) =>{
            console.log("write done correctly");
          });
    });
  });
});
```

The notification works fine but apparently on the client side I'm doing something wrong, this is the code I implemented.

In the main View Controller `ViewDidLoad` I register the `UserDefaults` value for key `badgeCount`:

```
var dict = [String: Any]()
    dict.updateValue(0, forKey: "badgeCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dict)
```

Then in app delegate I try to increment the badge using this function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    
    if let userInfoDict = userInfo as? [String : Any]{
        print("received notification :")
        print(userInfoDict)
    }
    
    if var badgeCount = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "badgeCount") as? Int{
        
        badgeCount += 1
        
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(badgeCount, forKey: "badgeCount")
        
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
    }
}
```

I also gave all the [image: permission] to the app that apparently allow It to receive notifications when app's in background but it still doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem modifying the payload adding this:

`content_available: "true",`

```
const notificationContent = {
        notification: {
          title: "New Message",
          body: "Watch this notification",
          icon: "default",
          sound: "notificationSound.wav",
          content_available: "true",
        },
      };
```